# How can I indicate that a generic class extends from one class or another?

Tags: java, class

Hi I have the next class

```
public class ApiResponse<T extends ApiResponseData >
```

When `T` is a type of the `ApiResponseData`, but sometimes I receive to a list instead of an object and for this case I need the `T` to be extended from `ApiResponseData` or `List<ApiResponseData>` how can do it this?

My attempt

```
public class ApiResponse<T extends ApiResponseData || T extends List<ApiResponseData>>
```

Comment: You can't. Because that makes no sense for the compiler. You will not be able to do anything with an instance of `T` because the compiler does not know if it will be a `ApiResponseData` or a `List< ApiResponseData>`. It would be able to call all the methods they have in common (`Object`) but then you can drop the generic all together because you have not gained anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible as because it will be **ambiguous** for java to decide which class to use during type erasing. You can use Generic to specify the constraint like T needs to be a subclass of multiple class like (A & B) like `<T extends A & B>` but your use case not possible.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of the purpose of generic type parameters. Why do you think you need the type parameter to change to accommodate lists?

Why is something like this not sufficient?

```
class ApiResponse<T extends ApiResponseData>
{
    final List<T> data;

    ApiResponse(T datum)
    {
        data = Collections.singletonList(datum);
    }

    ApiResponse(List<T> data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can await a  `public class ApiResponse<T extends List<ApiResponseData> >` and treat `T extends ApiResponseData` case, as a list of one element when calling this method (Higher in your code)